# increase element's padding by 1 in CSS only without knowing the current

Tags: html, css

I have an element with a certain padding that is I have no control of and can't pre-determine it's padding.
it is set in a different css file which I have no control over and that is generated dynamically and gives the element a random padding value.

I want to decrease it's padding by 1.

something like this:

```
#myElement{
 currentpadding+1px;
}
```

I haven't found a way do to this cross browser without using javascript.
I need to be using CSS only.

Comment: You can't, use js.

Comment: Not possible with CSS only.

Comment: Do you want to increase or decrease? You say decrease but then your example is increase.

Comment: both, sometimes I need to increase and sometimes decrease

Answer (score 2):

First add `box-sizing: border-box;` then apply border of desired width:

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#myElement {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement" class="box"><span></span></div>
<div class="box"><span></span></div>
```

Comment: In my scenario, simply replacing `padding-left: 2px` with `border-left: 2px solid transparent` achieved exactly the effect I wanted, effectively adding 2px of left padding to an element. Thanks for the tip, this is clever!